# Edittext with suggested text from corresponding row in database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext, row, autosuggest

Okay, this time as in title I need to have text suggestion in edittext BUT the suggestion must be pulled from the corresponding row in database. 
I have database set with 48 rows. No rows can be added as I disabled this functionality. Rows can be only updated. User must have an option to retain current content from the corresponding row or type a new content.

Does anybody have an idea how this could be achieved?
Thanks in advance.
Paddy

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

here is my Diary file:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;
public class Diary extends Activity {
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET1;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET2;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET3;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET4;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET5;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET6;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET7;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET8;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET9;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET10;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET11;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET12;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET13;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET14;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET15;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET16;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET17;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET18;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET19;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET20;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET21;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET22;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET23;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET24;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET25;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET26;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET27;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET28;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET29;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET30;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET31;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET32;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET33;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET34;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET35;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET36;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET37;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET38;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET39;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET40;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET41;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET42;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET43;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET44;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET45;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET46;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET47;
    AutoCompleteTextView titleET48;

    Button submitBT;
    MyDB dba;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.diary);
        dba = new MyDB(this);
        dba.open();



titleET1 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary1);

        titleET2 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary2);
        titleET3 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary3);
        titleET4 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary4);
        titleET5 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary5);
        titleET6 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary6);
        titleET7 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary7);
        titleET8 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary8);
        titleET9 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary9);
        titleET10 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary10);
        titleET11 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary11);
        titleET12 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary12);
        titleET13 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary13);
        titleET14 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary14);
        titleET15 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary15);
        titleET16 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary16);
        titleET17 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary17);
        titleET18 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary18);
        titleET19 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary19);
        titleET20 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary20);
        titleET21 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary21);
        titleET22 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary22);
        titleET23 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary23);
        titleET24 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary24);
        titleET25 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary25);
        titleET26 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary26);
        titleET27 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary27);
        titleET28 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary28);
        titleET29 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary29);
        titleET30 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary30);
        titleET31 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary31);
        titleET32 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary32);
        titleET33 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary33);
        titleET34 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary34);
        titleET35 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary35);
        titleET36 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary36);
        titleET37 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary37);
        titleET38 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary38);
        titleET39 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary39);
        titleET40 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary40);
        titleET41 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary41);
        titleET42 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary42);
        titleET43 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary43);
        titleET44 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary44);
        titleET45 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary45);
        titleET46 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary46);
        titleET47 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary47);
        titleET48 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.diary48);




        submitBT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitBT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    saveItToDB();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        });
    }



    public void saveItToDB() {
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET1.getText().toString(), 1);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET2.getText().toString(), 2);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET3.getText().toString(), 3);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET4.getText().toString(), 4);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET5.getText().toString(), 5);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET6.getText().toString(), 6);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET7.getText().toString(), 7);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET8.getText().toString(), 8);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET9.getText().toString(), 9);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET10.getText().toString(), 10);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET11.getText().toString(), 11);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET12.getText().toString(), 12);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET13.getText().toString(), 13);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET14.getText().toString(), 14);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET15.getText().toString(), 15);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET16.getText().toString(), 16);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET17.getText().toString(), 17);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET18.getText().toString(), 18);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET19.getText().toString(), 19);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET20.getText().toString(), 20);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET21.getText().toString(), 21);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET22.getText().toString(), 22);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET23.getText().toString(), 23);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET24.getText().toString(), 24);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET25.getText().toString(), 25);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET26.getText().toString(), 26);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET27.getText().toString(), 27);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET28.getText().toString(), 28);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET29.getText().toString(), 29);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET30.getText().toString(), 30);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET31.getText().toString(), 31);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET32.getText().toString(), 32);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET33.getText().toString(), 33);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET34.getText().toString(), 34);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET35.getText().toString(), 35);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET36.getText().toString(), 36);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET37.getText().toString(), 37);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET38.getText().toString(), 38);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET39.getText().toString(), 39);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET40.getText().toString(), 40);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET41.getText().toString(), 41);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET42.getText().toString(), 42);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET43.getText().toString(), 43);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET44.getText().toString(), 44);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET45.getText().toString(), 45);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET46.getText().toString(), 46);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET47.getText().toString(), 47);
        dba.updateDiaryEntry(titleET48.getText().toString(), 48);

        dba.close();
        titleET1.setText("");

        titleET2.setText("");
        titleET3.setText("");
        titleET4.setText("");
        titleET5.setText("");
        titleET6.setText("");
        titleET7.setText("");
        titleET8.setText("");
        titleET9.setText("");
        titleET10.setText("");
        titleET11.setText("");
        titleET12.setText("");
        titleET13.setText("");
        titleET14.setText("");
        titleET15.setText("");
        titleET16.setText("");
        titleET17.setText("");
        titleET18.setText("");
        titleET19.setText("");
        titleET20.setText("");
        titleET21.setText("");
        titleET22.setText("");
        titleET23.setText("");
        titleET24.setText("");
        titleET25.setText("");
        titleET26.setText("");
        titleET27.setText("");
        titleET28.setText("");
        titleET29.setText("");
        titleET30.setText("");
        titleET31.setText("");
        titleET32.setText("");
        titleET33.setText("");
        titleET34.setText("");
        titleET35.setText("");
        titleET36.setText("");
        titleET37.setText("");
        titleET38.setText("");
        titleET39.setText("");
        titleET40.setText("");
        titleET41.setText("");
        titleET42.setText("");
        titleET43.setText("");
        titleET44.setText("");
        titleET45.setText("");
        titleET46.setText("");
        titleET47.setText("");
        titleET48.setText("");


        Intent i = new Intent(Diary.this, Monday.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the Back button */
    public void visitMonday(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Monday.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And here is the function that I am supposed to insert into onCreate() method:

```
private void initializeDescription() {
    _descriptionText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    final int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    final String[] from = new String[]{VehicleDescriptionsTable.DESCRIPTION};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            null,
            from,
            to);

    // This will provide the labels for the choices to be displayed in the AutoCompleteTextView
    adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            final int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(VehicleDescriptionsTable.DESCRIPTION);
            return cursor.getString(colIndex);
        }
    });

    // This will run a query to find the descriptions for a given vehicle.
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence description) {
            String vehicle = getSelectedVehicle();
            Cursor managedCursor = _helper.getDescriptionsFor(vehicle, description.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "Query has " + managedCursor.getCount() + " rows of description for " + vehicle);
            return managedCursor;
        }
    });

    _descriptionText.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Unfortunately when I insert this function into onCreate() method error pops up saying that there is error at tokens { and } . What am I doing wrong?

I want the edittext to show predefined text from corresponding row in the table.

Edit---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I tried AutoCompleteTextView with CursorAdapter but I cannot see the option to pull information from rows in database. What am I missing here?

Comment: Here's one way: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

Comment: @KenWolf this is not what I am looking for unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

[AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) is what you are looking for.

How to use it :

1. Change your `EditText` TO `AutoCompleteTextView`
2. Create your `Adapter` class : in this case a `CursorAdapter` will suit better to fetch data from database. You can fetch your database data in a `Cursor` object then pass it to a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) ([here is a tuto](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)). Or if you want a custom adapter, create a new class that `extends` the `CursorAdapter` base class.
3. Set the adapter for the `AutoCompleteTextView` field

   `autoCompleteView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: It sounds all right but I don't know where to start exactly. I changed all edittext into AutoCompleteTextView and I don't know what to do next. From what you say I undestand that I need to create new class named CursorAdapter. And here I don't know exactly what to do within this class.

Comment: Not exactly. You just need an adapter to give to your `AutoCompleteTextView`. check my edit.

Comment: Try to follow the links I provided and read carefully the explanations. You will achieve this easily after that ;)

Comment: look at [this](http://www.opgenorth.net/blog/2011/09/06/using-autocompletetextview-and-simplecursoradapter-2) and [this](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/). Good luck

Comment: I followed the tuto to create class and two xml files but I don't know how to refine code for my own need

Comment: I tried your tutorials but I cannot achieve the point from where code works fine. I get errors when inserting methods from tutorials.

Comment: I am stuck at point 3. set the adapter for the AutoCompleTextView field. ANy more help from you Mansoulx?

Comment: @mansoulx these tutorials show how to implement suggested words from database, and I need something that will populate edittext straight away with data from corresponding row in a table...

Comment: Let's continue [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50581/edittext-with-suggested-text-from-corresponding-row-in-database)

Comment: I am unable to use chat yet :(

Comment: basically from what I have seen in your tutorials there are options to use dropdown for example to enable pick selection. I just need direct pull of data from corresponding row straight into edittext, so the user may have an option to retain old data or change it.